# How to put a condition in jQuery's map function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to put a condition in jQuery's map function. My issue is that I don't want the same number in the map function value. When it is the same I want to display an alert box. My map function code is like this:

```
var rankbox= $('input[type=text][class = cate_rank]').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();
```

If I get a value like `1,2,3,4,5` it's ok, but if I get a value like `1,2,3,2,5`, I want to display an alert box. Is it possible?

How to put a condition in jQuery's map function?

```
function  change_rank() {
  var rankbox= $('input[type=text][class = cate_rank]').map(function() {
    if() {
    } else { }
    return this.value;
  }).get();
```

Comment: You just gave yourself an answer or what? ;-)

Comment: yes, what condition i have to put ?

Comment: and what conditions do you want to be met?

Comment: I already mention in questions. If I get a value like 1,2,3,4,5 it's ok, but if I get a value like 1,2,3,2,5, I want to display an alert box. Is it possible?

Comment: But what's wrong with second set? You didn't say what is the condition... just one example that doesn't give an idea what you want. Check my answer, may be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var vals = []
$('input[type=text][class = cate_rank]').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() && (typeof vals[$(this).val()] == 'undefined')){
        vals[$(this).val()] = 1;
        var last_val = $(this).val();
    }else if($(this).val() && (typeof last_val != 'undefined')  && parseInt(last_val) > parseInt($(this).val())){
        alert('Whooah! Something went terribly wrong! Inputs don\'t have values ordered incrementally!');
    }else{
        alert('Whooah! Something went wrong! We got two inputes with same value!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
var rankbox= $(".test").map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();

var sorted_arr = rankbox.slice().sort(); 

var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rankbox.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
        results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
}
var rankbox= $(".test").map(function() {
  if($.inArray(this.value, results) > -1){
  alert(this.value+" is duplicate");
  }
  return this.value;
}).get();
```

I took reference of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

If you are Looking to check dup you can try this:

```js
var x=[1,2,3,2,5]
var has=!x.every(function(v,i) {
   return x.indexOf(v) == i;
 });

 console.log(has);//true means dup found else not found.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with a object. check this:

---

```
function  change_rank() {
  var temp = {};
  var rankbox= $('input[type=text][class = cate_rank]').map(function() {
    if(temp[this.value]==undefined) {
      temp[this.value] = this.value;
    } else {
      alert('the same value');
    }
    return this.value;
}).get();
```